# Can a continuous mean zero process be turned into a semimartingale via a change of measure?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $X_t$ be a continuous process such that $E[X_t] = 0$ for all t. Denote by $\mathcal F_t$ the completion of its natural filtration.

Does there exist some $F_{\infty}$-measurable non negative random variable $Z$ with $\int Z \ d\mathbb P = 1$ such that under the probability measure $\mathbb Q$ defined by

$$d \mathbb Q = Z \ d \mathbb P$$

$X_t$ is an $F_t$-semimartingale?

Comment: Fix a positive function $f$ with unbounded variation. Toss a coin, set $X_t = f(t)$ if it turns heads, $X_t = -f(t)$ otherwise. Clearly, $E[X_t]=0$, but $X_t$ cannot be turned into a semimartingale via any change of measure.

Comment: Ah.. that makes semse.